# Atualizar navegador VBA

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, excel-vba

Tenho umamacro q faz webscrapp no internet Explorer, mas o site é bem ruim e às vezes trava. Gostaria de colocar no loop um código que força o IE a atualizar se demorar muito pra carregar, travar ou não der um erro que ative o resume next.
o loop eh o seguinte:
Preenche o nome do cliente > clica em pesquisar. Nesse momento a trava (quando acontece) acontece de tres formas: Às vezes o IE fica rodando, as vezes ele retorna servidor não encontrado, e as vezes retorna cliente não localizado, e nesses casos a Macro não considera erro, e não segue pra próxima linha.
Eu gostaria q iniciasse um timer logo após clicar em pesquisar, pra atualizar o navegador se demorar tipo 2 minutos pra reiniciar o loop. A rotina on error não processa quando o IE retorna servidor não encontrado, e a Macro só volta a rodar se eu atualizar manualmente o navegador.

Answer (score 0):

Se o site é bem ruim então você está em maus lençóis, pois, o IE também o é...
Quando utilizava o IE para webscraping fiz a função abaixo. Ainda assim há o risco de se enfrentar um loop eterno. Hoje estou aprendendo a lidar com o Selenium, manipulando o Chrome Driver.

```
Function fnCheckDocReadyState(ByRef objIE As InternetExplorer) As Boolean
    Dim curTimer As Currency
    Dim oDoc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument

    curTimer = Timer
    On Error Resume Next
    Set oDoc = objIE.document
    On Error GoTo 0
    If Not (oDoc Is Nothing) Then
        Do While objIE.document.readyState <> "complete"
            DoEvents: DoEvents: DoEvents
            If Timer - curTimer > 10 Then
                objIE.Refresh2
                curTimer = Timer
            End If
        Loop
        fnCheckDocReadyState = True
    End If
lblSair:
    Exit Function
End Function
```